# Testing a Mongoose schema array of strings

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I have the following Mongoose schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const promoCodesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    couponId: String,
    value: Number,
    codes: [
      {
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
        trim: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  { strict: true, timestamps: true },
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('PromoCodes', promoCodesSchema)
```

I would like to test that `codes` is an array of string and that I cannot pass anything else. I have the following test:

```js
 it("asserts that the codes field are only array of strings", async() => {
    const validPromoCodesWithInvalidCodesField = new PromoCodes({
      couponId: "rate20",
      value: 20,
      codes: ["azeerr", 2, 6],
      rate: 2
    });
    
    const savedValidPromoCodesWithInvalidCodesField = await validPromoCodesWithInvalidCodesField.save()
    expect(savedValidPromoCodesWithInvalidCodesField._id).toBeDefined();
    expect(savedValidPromoCodesWithInvalidCodesField.codes).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(["AZEERR", "2", "6"]));
  })
```

My tests show me that `codes: ["azeerr", 2, 6]` is changed to `["AZEERR", "2", "6"]` before being added to the db, but what I would like is that codes accept only an array of strings.

How can I test this, maybe my schema declaration is wrong, or my tests?